# conda update failed in windows 10

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

In Anaconda prompt as an administrator (Window 10 - 64 bit) after this command : **conda update --all** I see these errors as below:
I want to update and install packages but after enter every command these errors appear.

```
conda update --all
Fetching package metadata ..........An unexpected error has occurred.
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues



Current conda install:

               platform : win-64
          conda version : 4.2.9
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.2.9
    conda-build version : 2.0.2
         python version : 3.5.2.final.0
       requests version : 2.11.1
       root environment : D:\Anaconda3  (writable)
    default environment : D:\Anaconda3
       envs directories : D:\Anaconda3\envs
          package cache : D:\Anaconda3\pkgs
           channel URLs : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/win-64/
                          http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/noarch/
                          http://github.com/scipy/scipy.git/win-64/
                          http://github.com/scipy/scipy.git/noarch/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch/
            config file : C:\Users\Behnaz Eslami\.condarc
           offline mode : False



`$ D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py update --all`




    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 131, in fetch_repodata
        cache = json.loads(json_str)
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 473, in conda_exception_handler
        return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 144, in _main
        exit_code = args.func(args, p)
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 65, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'update')
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 238, in install
        prefix=prefix)
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\api.py", line 24, in get_index
        index = fetch_index(channel_urls, use_cache=use_cache, unknown=unknown)
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 293, in fetch_index
        for url in urls]
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 293, in <listcomp>
        for url in urls]
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 70, in func
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\fetch.py", line 137, in fetch_repodata
        .format(url, filename, e))
    conda.exceptions.CondaRuntimeError: Runtime error: Invalid index file: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/win-64/repodata.json: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to run `conda update conda` on command prompt (admin)

or Go to your **anaconda installation folder**, `right-click` on "**Anaconda3**", go to `Security`, in "**Group or user names**" click on `Users`, then check all under "**Allow**".

[See this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFz7S.png)

Comment: I have this problem with my 2021 installation of Miniconda3.    The accepted answer appears to be stale, or not applicable.  Help please?

Answer (score 0):

instead of running running in a normal terminal window or as administrator, open an anaconda terminal.

1. In the windows 10 search bar, type `cmd` (don't press enter)
2. In the results, you should see one titled "Anaconda prompt (anaconda 3)"
3. type your command in this anaconda terminal e.g. `conda update conda`

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add the following reference** to your (environment variables) path:

```
<AnacondaInstallationDirectory>\condabin
```

**It's important to add it before any other existing Anaconda references there**, so that `conda.exe` can be executed with the right privileges.

Also you make sure that you have these as well:

```
<AnacondaInstallationDirectory>\Library\bin
<AnacondaInstallationDirectory>\Scripts
<AnacondaInstallationDirectory>
```