# conda update --all fails in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, anaconda, conda

I have already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690045/conda-update-failed-in-windows-10), but it is not the same as the problem I am encountering.

I just ran

```
C:\Users\USRNAME\Documents> conda update conda
```

and the command ran without any error.  Then I attempted to run

```
C:\Users\USRNAME\Documents> conda update --all
```

and I began to get the following error:

```
C:\Users\USRNAME\Documents>conda update anaconda
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
/Microsoft was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\USRNAME\Documents>@FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('@CALL C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Anaconda3_64\Scripts\conda.exe shell.cmd.exe reactivate') DO @SET "_TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH=%i"

C:\Users\USRNAME\Documents>
```

This has never happened before.  Usually, I am able to run `conda update conda` and `conda update --all` once a week without any kind of problem.  Any help in solving the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: @ close voters: This question is definitely not off-topic. Anaconda (and conda) are directly used for programming. This seems like a bug in conda. What version of conda do you have? `conda --version`

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried everything to resolve the problem, but without success. The root of the problem was that there was a conflict between the Python that is installed with Visual Studio (when the Python Tools option is selected), and the version that is installed from Anaconda. And after spending nearly a day, the only clean solution I could manage was to uninstall Python Tools from Visual Studio and use the version from Anaconda. My advice to anyone else running into this problem would be to ensure that he has only one operational version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a certain environment, like:

```
conda update -n myenv --all
```